# SQL Server Comma separate string in column and and search values without using split method and check should be AND instead of OR

Tags: sql

I have comma separated string value in a column.
**Example** "WX,AB,XYZ", "WX,CD,NY"
Now in sql if I received "WX,XYZ" it should return "WX,AB,XYZ" only not "WX,CD,NY". Basically its AND comparison between comma separated values.
PS: I cannot use split method because of performance issue.

Comment: In short search comma separated string without using split function

Comment: Left or right, you're not going to get great performance. SQL isn't made for this

Comment: @HoneyBadger whats the solution? I cannot change existing architecture for now atleast.

Comment: The solution if you can't fix the model? Take a deep breath, have a cup of coffee, learn to enjoy waiting. SQL is great, but it can't work miracles

Comment: @HoneyBadger Changing structure would be last solution. Yes I will have a cup of coffee in order to find any solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Comma delimited strings are a *really* bad idea.  You should revisit your design.  But if you are stuck with someone else's really, really bad design decision, then you can use `string_split()` (at least in the more recent versions of SQL Server):

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*)
       from split_string(t.col, ',') s1 join
            split_string(@input, ',') s2
            on s1.value = s2.value
      ) = (select count(*) from split_string(@input, ','));
```

This formulation assumes that none of the strings have duplicate values.

Comment: split function is causing performance issue.with split method query is taking 1.2 secs.

Comment: @Faisal . . . Don't store multiple values in a single column.  Fix the data. model if you care about performance.

Comment: I cannot update db structure for now as multiple apps are depending on 1 db.I know its structural problem but still looking for work around without updating existing structure.

Comment: @Faisal . . . With this data structure, you need a full text scan of the table -- and that is probably the cause of the performance issue.  Your only other option is a full text index on the column.